# Expected ',' instead of 't' in Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a beginner when it comes to API's and JSON serialization. I'm encountering a weird output. It seems that my JSON output is being wrongly formatted? I am using spring boot 1.59 and when I check my result in postman I am getting the following error:

### controller

```
 /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping(value = "/getUser")
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUSer(@RequestParam int userID) {
         System.out.println("Request Id is---->"+userID);
         User user = userRepository.findById(userID);
        return user;
    }
```

### User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 65)
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 65)
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 128)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "user")
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    // Hibernate requires a no-arg constructor
    public User() {

    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }

    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }
}
```

### UserProfile

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profiles")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    @Size(max = 15)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 10)
    private Gender gender;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dob")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String address1;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String address2;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String street;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String city;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String state;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    @Size(max = 32)
    private String zipCode;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public UserProfile() {

    }

    public UserProfile(String phoneNumber, Gender gender, Date dateOfBirth, 
                       String address1, String address2, String street, String city, 
                       String state, String country, String zipCode) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

### UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   User findById(int id);
}
```

As well as a big long stack trace of fasterxml.jackson errors:

```
[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at
```

Comment: So, when you run the API from postman, you hit the server, it processes and then you get exception during output. Is that right?. Or do you not even got the server? Can you post the sample API request you are firing from postman.

Comment: Post the whole stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

It happened due to infinite recursion between two entities and I solved using **JsonManagedReference**, **JsonBackReference**